# Applying a multiplier to a random-resulted number

Tags: python

newbie here.

OK so long story short, I've made a var that will output a random number between 70 and 155:

```
T_dmg = random.randrange(70,155)
```

And this is my "multiplier":

```
def crit(cr):
    return cr * 2
```

Crit stands for critical but I am not sure how to use the "return" statement. So I added this function to the line before the number gets added up:

```
if Toni > 0:
        crit(T_dmg)
        Xoni = Xoni - T_dmg
```

Problem is the output is never multiplied because somehow, the "crit" function doesn't seem to apply to it.
Xoni is a var that has a value of 7000. If this doesn't make sense, I'm using HP from game concepts. I hope any of you can shed some light.

Thanks!

Edit: Chance code:

```
def critchance():
    random.randrange(1,10)
    if critchance() == "3"
    crit()
```

Comment: I have no idea, I just thought I should fill in the parenthesis...

Comment: Maybe `T_dmg = crit(T_dmg)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns a value - it doesn't change the input variable. You still have to assign `T_dmg` to the output of the function.

```
T_dmg = crit(T_dmg)
```

Otherwise `T_dmg` will stay the same, giving you the "strange" results.

Your `critchance` function is also off - it's infinitely recursive. We need to fix this. Also, you seem to be calling the `crit` function with no arguments.  You should probably pass `T_dmg` as a parameter to this function.

```
def critchance(cr):
    if random.randrange(1, 10) == 3:
        return crit(cr)
    return cr
```

Then to call it, do this.

```
T_dmg = critchance(T_dmg)
```

Comment: I see but I forgot to tell you that I am planning to add a "chance" for this.

A 10% chance that it is going to be multiplied by 2x. I have already defined the "chance" function but first I can't seem to fix the multiplier.

Comment: @user2113324 Could you explain that in your original question? And what's the code for the "chance" function?

Comment: def critchance():
    random.randrange(1,10)
    if critchance() == "3"
    crit()

Comment: @user2113324 edit your original question - comments aren't good for long bits of code.

Comment: I am looking at it right now but there are a lots of things I don't understand yet. I think I'll bookmark this page after I learn the define statement better. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2113324 There is are a couple of resources that I would recommend for you to use. One of the greatest [basic tutorials](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/) is extremely helpful for questions such as this. Since you are obviously new to python, I would recommend trying some of the [Euler Problems](https://projecteuler.net/) which will expand you knowledge. And, as always, use the Stack! :)